# Then code of an axios.get not completed and error catched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I'm trying to understand the flow of following code using `console.log` traces:

```
function fetchTsValues() {

    console.log("fetchTsValues");

    axios.get(urlValues)
        .then(result => valuesToChannel(result.data))
        .catch(() => setError('Impossible to get TS values'));
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchTsValues();
}, []);

function valuesToChannel(TSDetailAPI) {

    console.log(TSDetailAPI);
    console.log("valuesToChannel");

    const updatedChannels = {...channels};
    console.log("updatedChannels - 1", updatedChannels);
    updatedChannels[TSDetailAPI.name].series = buildSeries(TSDetailAPI.values);

    console.log("updatedChannels - 2", updatedChannels);
    setChannels(updatedChannels);
    setIsLoading(false);
}

console.log("error", error);
```

The traces are following ones:

```
fetchTsValues
valuesToChannel
updatedChannels - 1 {demo-temperature-1: {…}}
error Impossible to get TS values
```

What I don't understand is why I start to run `valuesToChannel` initial instructions before being stopped by the catch of `fetchTsValues` `axios.get`. The `get` runs correctly with a 200 return status code.

I could understand to finish the `then` and then if the promise is not delivered to move to the `catch`. But here the code is not even ending the `then` clause. **What am I doing wrong or not understanding?**

*Note: this code is part of a wider react context. But I think that I have properly figured out a reduced context.*

Comment: You may be getting values with a 200 status code, but if you get an error thrown in your valuesToChannel function it will still be caught by your .catch because it is being called in your promise chain. Is it possible buildSeries is giving an error? You could try wrapping the inside of valuesToChannel in a Try/Catch block to narrow it down. [Try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: @Charlie Thanks for your precious comment. This seems a promising way to find my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Charlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11000058/charlie), I was able to fix my error.

I learnt that using [Try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) is efficient to detect error thrown in unexpected areas of code!